# static class member gets "undefined reference". Don't know why

Tags: c++, static, class-members

I don't know what is wrong with this code. I have the following, very simple, class:

```
class SetOfCuts{
public:

  static LeptonCuts   Leptons;
  static ElectronCuts TightElectrons;
  static ElectronCuts LooseElectrons;
  //***
  //more code
};
```

and, for example, the type ElectronCuts is defined before in the same .h file as:

```
struct ElectronCuts{
  bool Examine;
  //****
  //other irrelevant stuff
};
```

Nothing too complicated, I think.

My understanding is that, in the main program, I can do:

```
SetOfCuts::LooseElectrons.Examine = true;
```

but if I do this, I get:

```
 undefined reference to `SetOfCuts::LooseElectrons'
```

If, instead, I do:

```
 bool SetOfCuts::LooseElectrons.Examine = true;
```

I get:

```
error: expected initializer before '.' token
```

I don't know why I cannot access the members of the structs. I am missing something obvious about static data members but I don't know what it is.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any static reference must be declared also in a specific source file (and not only in the header file) since it must exists somewhere when linking is done.

For example if you have this in your `Foo.h`

```
class SetOfCuts{
public:

  static LeptonCuts   Leptons;
  static ElectronCuts TightElectrons;
  static ElectronCuts LooseElectrons;
};
```

Then in `Foo.cpp` you will have

```
#include <Foo.h>
LeptonCuts SetOfCuts::Leptons = whatever;
ElectronCuts SetOfCuts::ThighElectrons = whatever;
..
```

Finally in your main.cpp you will be able to do

```
#include <Foo.h>
SetOfCuts::Leptons = whatever;
```

Answer (score 3):

The "undefined reference" error you're getting is a linker error saying that you've *declared* the static data members, but you haven't actually *defined* them anywhere.  In C++, there are two steps to using a static variable - you first specify it in the class, as you've done, and then have to actually put a definition of it somewhere.  This is similar to how you define functions in a header - you prototype the function in the header, then provide the implementation in the source file.

In your case, in the source file in which you've implemented the member functions for `SetOfCuts`, add the following lines:

```
LeptonCuts SetOfCuts::Leptons;
ElectronCuts SetOfCuts::TightElectrons;
ElectronCuts SetOfCuts:LooseElectrons;
```

This tells C++ in what translation unit the static members are actually defined.  You can also specify constructor arguments here if you would like.  Note that you do *not* repeat the `static` keyword here.

Hope this helps!